# Let $x, y, z$ be vectors in a vector space $V$ such that $x+y+z=0$. Show that $\operatorname{span}(x, y) = \operatorname{span}(y, z)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I incorporate $\def\sp{\operatorname{span}}\sp(x,y)=\sp(-y-z,y)=\sp(y,z)$ into a proof?

Comment: It would depend on what is trying to be proved in the proof... Or do you mean how would you prove the above?

Comment: If you've shown $\def\sp{\operatorname{span}}\sp(x,y)=\sp(-y-z,y)=\sp(y,z)$, then that _is_ a proof.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a start for a proof. To show that two spans are equal, take $w\in \operatorname{span}(x,y)$. We'll try to show that $w\in \operatorname{span}(y,z)$. Now, we know that $w=ax+by$ for some scalars $a,b$. But, $x+y+z=0$, so $x=-y-z$. Thus $w=ax+by=a(-y-z)+by$ which is a combination of $y$ and $z$. In other words, $w\in \operatorname{span}(y,z)$. What does this show? Can you finish the proof now?

Comment: This is much more complicated than the elementary equational argument that is contained in the question...

Comment: I wasn't entire sure what the question actually was so I offered the least complicated (i.e., does not involve anything else) and most straightforward proof.

Answer (score 0):

For the record I'll repeat my comment: using the basic properties of '$\def\sp{\operatorname{span}}\sp$' you have shown that $\sp(x,y)=\sp(y,z)$ when $x=-y-z$, and that is precisely the proof that was asked. There is nothing left to do.